# redux-form never calls validation for react native app

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-form

I'm totally expecting this to be solved by "look, your forgot a comma there" or something silly, but I really can't see it. I've stripped the problem down to a basic react native app with only one redux form.

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer, Field } from 'redux-form'
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ forms: formReducer })
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(logger))

const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {}
  if (!values.name) errors.name = 'Required'
  if (!values.email) errors.email = 'Required'
  return errors
}

const renderInput = ({ input: { onChange, ...restInput } }) => {
  return <TextInput onChangeText={onChange} {...restInput} />
}

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  submit = (values) => console.log('Submitting ', values)

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <Text>Please fill in this form:</Text>
        <Field name='name' component={renderInput} />
        <Field name='email' component={renderInput} />
        <Button title='Go' onPress={handleSubmit(this.submit)} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const MyConnectedForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myform',
  validate
})(MyForm)

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MyConnectedForm />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

I can see that the events:

@@redux-form/CHANGE 
@@redux-form/BLUR

are being fired, and that the redux state of the form changes. validate however is only being called once, on the first render and never again. Also, when I press the button, the submit function is being called with an empty object, instead of the values of the form like I was expecting.

Versions used:

- redux: 3.7.2
- redux-form: 7.3.0
- react: 16.3.1
- react-native: 0.55.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost as bad as a misplaced comma. I used the key, **forms** and then later **form**.